How can I calculate the probability of detection and false alarm rate of a correlation result assuming a given SNR threshold in AWGN?
I am transmitting an LFM chirp with fixed bandwidth $B$ and sample rate $f_{s}$, containing $N$ samples. The chirp is windowed with a Kaiser window, which generally has constant $\beta$ but can vary. The chirp has a fixed peak power $P_{0}$ determined by the hardware.
The receiver correlates the received signal against a copy of the non-windowed LFM chirp, and I am thresholding the result to identify valid signal detections.
I am trying to understand how to calculate the probability of detection and false alarm rate given an AWGN channel for a given noise variance and detection threshold.
